# Laravel 5.7 route exists, but shows 404

Tags: laravel-5

I ran route:list and as you can see, the controller, and route is there.

```
|        | POST     | videos                 |                  | App\Http\Controllers\VideoController@store                             | web,auth     |
```

And if I post to videos it gets 404. Its not the controller, because I tried returing just a string from the route.

I tried route:cache and cache:clear

Comment: try to restart your server

Comment: I am using php artisan serve... and I did restart

Comment: curl 'http://localhost:8000/video'   <<< not valid route, gets laravel error, while curl 'http://localhost:8000/videos' (valid route) gets a server 404... not sure if that makes sense

Comment: can you share with as you web.php file, please?

Comment: umm isn't it post suppose to show 404 because it's not GET? post can return redirect()->route("") or redirect()->url("") or response()->json([""]) or back()->with([""]) but why VIEW in post ?

Comment: Route::get('/', 'PublicController@index')->name('public');
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']], function () {
    Route::get('upload','VideoUploadController@index');
    Route::post('upload','VideoUploadController@store');
    Route::post('videos','VideoController@store');
    Route::get('videos','VideoController@index');
    Route::get('videos/{video}','VideoController@show');    
    Route::put('/videos/{video}','VideoController@update');
});

and yes, I was testing with post...

Comment: get /videos fails and post /videos fails, get /videos/id works

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was a conflict with public folder. I downloaded a template which had videos folder, and so webserver tried to load that instead of sending it to Laravel.